# Pass Windows Authentication between IIS servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET web application which uses a WCF IIS-based backend service.

I can use Active Directory Authentication for the web application, but I would like to use it also on the WCF service (which is on another IIS server).

Is it possible to do this via configurations only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.
In web app config set:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport  clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>            
 </security>
```

In WCF-part:

```
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
     <binding>
         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
         </security>
     </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Thing is i need to sleep more.